# Select CoreNLP language model at runtime

Tags: stanford-nlp

Is it possible to select language models (among the official ones: English, Chinese, Spanish) at runtime by using the Java API?

I am currently using Gradle to define dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'edu.stanford.nlp', name: 'stanford-corenlp', version: '3.5.1'
    compile group: 'edu.stanford.nlp', name: 'stanford-corenlp', version: '3.5.1', classifier: 'models'
}
```

Also, are Chinese and Spanish models available on Maven as well?

Answer (score 2):

The Stanford CoreNLP main JAR file (as distributed on Maven) contains properties files `StanfordCoreNLP-spanish.properties`, `StanfordCoreNLP-chinese.properties`. You can load these programmatically from the classpath and use them when instantiating the `StanfordCoreNLP` pipeline.

Unfortunately we don't distribute the multilingual models on Maven, though that could probably change if there is community demand.

Comment: That would definitely be a plus. By the way, I am using CoreNLP to achieve lemmatization, therefore I use the `Morphology` class to lemmatize single (already POS-tagged) terms. Is there a way to load those `properties` files to be used in that context only?

Comment: @Jon: The Stanford Core main JAR file doesn't contain the .properties files as you describe. The language specific properties files are bundeled in the language specific model JARS. So you have to include these JARS first in your classpath and then load the properties you want; for example with: `props.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("StanfordCoreNLP-german.properties"));`

Answer (score 1):

This is more a comment than an answer, but I am new so I'm being blocked from comments!  We are actively working on adding the Spanish and Chinese models to Maven, so stay tuned, they should be out fairly soon!

**UPDATE**

You can now get the Chinese, Spanish, and German model jars on Maven!

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
   <classifier>models-chinese</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to include stanford core NLP into gradle dependency:

```
compile('edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.6.0')
compile('edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.6.0:models')
```